# Bootstrap design idea

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to get an idea from you guys. I have 3 checkboxes that I would like to display one in each line inside a box, kind of like a text area. What Bootstrap tool would allow me to accomplish that?

I tried to create a text area and out my checkboxes in them, but the code is translated as text in the text area. So I could not do that. What's the way of doing it?

Comment: Do you mean the `textarea` element? A textarea isn't a *box*. It's a form element where user can type text and it appears by default with a border around it. You're looking for CSS styling (put your checkboxes AND their labels (you've got labels, right?) in a paragraph and your problem is solved.

Comment: The `p` element is a paragraph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't restrict yourself to using *only* Bootstrap elements when making your site. Bootstrap is just a collection of nifty elements; it's fine (and probably necessary) to make your own, too.

If you just want your checkboxes to be in a box with an outline, well, that's a bit too simple for there to be a corresponding Bootstrap element.

In the simplest form, the HTML and CSS for this would look like [this JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/33FSA/)

## Html

```
<div class='checkbox-container'>
  <input type='checkbox' id='one'>
  <label for='one'>Hello</label>
</div>
```

## Css

```
.checkbox-container {
  margin: 10px 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

If you want all of the checkboxes in a single box, then you can do that with just a bit more code. [View on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/33FSA/1/)

If for some strange reason you must only use use Bootstrap elements, ananda's answer is pretty good. Using the well element gives you a border, but also an inner shadow and a background color. [**View the well on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HfbCU/)

Comment: @jmeas,instead of having three divs, I was looking for one div having three textboxes one in each row.

Answer (score 0):

try putting them inside the 'well' element

Comment: what do you mean by that? I think well element is used to give the grayish background. Its not gonna do what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: no. try reading the doc and find that it doesnt just give you a gray bg. well is actually used to give another element an inset effect! so it serves your purpose exactly.

Comment: I read the document, and indeed you are correct. But, I don't think its possible without using css as well, what do you think?

Comment: if you want a different bg color, then yes!